# Create node with specific internal id using LOAD CSV

Tags: neo4j

for initial data import (step 1) into Neo4j database I'm using the neo4j-admin import tool. There you can specify the internal id of a node by :ID in the header.

I would also like to use `LOAD CSV` command for creating more nodes (step 2) into an already existing database (with data from previous step). I can't find the answer on how to specify internal id of a node by using this command.

Why it is not possible, while at initial import it is? In second step I'm having a similar csv files as in the first step, which means I have a csv file of nodes with first column being an id of a node AND I have a csv file of relationships between them with columns be like start_id,end_id,relationshipType.

Thanks, Petr M

Comment: Also a lot of people would suggest to overcome this problem by simply creating my own property called "nodeID" for example. This would require additional indexing, which is completely useless in my opinion since I could easily use an already indexed internal ID

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood how the `ID`s contained in the [import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/) input files are used. They are not used as native IDs.

The `ID`s in the input data files are only used to enable the `import` tool to know that node X in file A is supposed to be the same as node Y in file B. After the import is completed, the `ID`s from the files are forgotten.

Whenever a node is created, the neo4j server always decides on its own what the actual native ID will be.

Also, it is never recommended to store native IDs in the DB, since it is not a reliable way to identify a specific entity (node or relationship) over time. After an entity is deleted, its native ID can be re-assigned to a new entity.

Comment: As a note, the internal graph id acts like a pointer to the node data within the node data store, which is one strong reason why setting internal graph ids isn't allowed.